# How to use mongoose in cloudflare workers

Tags: mongoose, cloudflare-workers

Is there any way to use mongodb in cloudflare wokers? Thanks.
I want to use flare wokers cloud but use mongodb.
I have searched many places and tried many ways but it doesn't work, currently cloudflare workers don't support mongoose but is there any way?
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did u resolve it?